# Basic AJAX script not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to load a file and display it in the div section of my web page, using AJAX. 
 The console output shows that the XMLHttpRequest object is successfully created, but then nothing happens: the callback function is never called and the content of the URL is not fetched.

```
<body>
    <div id="demo"><p>Some text</p></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request URL</button>
    <script>
        function loadDoc() {
            var xhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                console.log('object created'); // this message is printed
                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Mіcrosoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                console.log('inside callback function'); // this message is never printed 
                if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }
                xhttp.open("GET", "http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6120.txt", true);
                xhttp.send(null);
            };
        }
        console.log('end of script'); // this message is printed
    </script>
</body>
```

I don't know much about HTTP requests and I'm assuming that AJAX can be used to load an url that is perfectly accessible to my web browser.
 
Is this assumption incorrect? If not, then what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your code

```
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log('inside callback function'); 
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6120.txt", true);
        xhttp.send(null);
```

You must to send the request and the callback will be fired automatically. If you put that code inside the callback, you never achieve the request to the txt file

Comment: Yes, of course. I just didn't see the mistake in the code. Much appreciated.